# React runtime error when doing async call in a NextJS 13 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to do async calls with the new app layout of NextJS 13. I'm following the [new doc page](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching). But I keep getting this error

[image: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: \[object Promise\]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]

Here is what it looks like in `app/page.tsx`, not sure what I'm missing

```
'use client';

const getPlaces = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCAL_URL}/api/places`, {cache: 'no-store'});

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  return res.json();
}

const Home = async () => {
  const places = await getPlaces();
  console.log(places);

  return (
    <div className={'text-left'}>Homepage</div>
  )
};

export default Home;
```

The log correctly data, so the endpoint should be OK

Comment: Could you show where this error originates from?

Comment: @Jellyfish Added a screenshot with the call stack

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the `useState` hook to store the fetched data in the component's state rather than  `async`? I've gotten issues using async as well; using useState/useEffect might be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `fetch` function.

If you remove `use client` directive, your code will work in server component

If you remove the fetching function inside `use client` component, your app will still render.

From [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching)

> #### use in Client Components
>
> use is a new React function that accepts a promise conceptually similar to await. use handles the promise
> returned by a function in a way that is compatible with components,
> hooks, and Suspense. Learn more about use in the React RFC.
>
> Wrapping fetch in use is currently not recommended in Client
> Components and may trigger multiple re-renders. For now, if you need
> to fetch data in a Client Component, we recommend using a third-party
> library such as SWR or React Query